API call works fine on desktop, but not on mobile
I have a mobile app that I have made using React Native Expo. The back-end is an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. From the mobile app I try to make an API call to the back-end, but it does not work at all, instead I get this error:

Registration failed: Network Error

I made the API call from my desktop using Postman and it works perfectly. The call was not made to localhost, it was made using my IPv4 address.
I pinged the IPv4 address from my mobile phone using an app and it worked.
Then I tried to make a call using Postman web on my mobile device, but the error I got there is

Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to reserved address. Make sure address is publicly accessible or select a different agent.

which did not help me much, either.
I have also removed UseHttpsRedirection(); from my Program.cs in my back-end, since I read it could be the issue, but it did not help.
Also, I have added .AllowAnyOrigin(), .AllowAnyHeader() and .AllowAnyMethod() in my Program.cs to the CORS policies, but that did not help either.
So, now I am unsure what could be the issue. Below I have my Program.cs from my back-end and a bit of my React Native code that makes the request.
Program.cs backend code:
namespace Fitness_Tracker
{
    using Fitness_Tracker.Data;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Data.Models;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Infrastructure;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Services.Admins;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Services.Consumables;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Services.Meals;
    using Fitness_Tracker.Services.Users;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
    using System.Text;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<IUserService, UserService>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IMealService, MealService>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IAdminService, AdminService>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IConsumableService, ConsumableService>();

            builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                //@dev Change the options later. Current options are only for developement purposes
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]))
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Administrator"));
            });

            builder.Services.AddControllers();

            builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowReactApp",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                               .AllowAnyHeader()
                               .AllowAnyMethod();
                    });
            });

            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
            {
                serverOptions.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 7009);
            });

            builder.Logging.AddConsole();

            var app = builder.Build();

            using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                DataSeeder.SeedActivityLevels(services).Wait();
                DataSeeder.SeedAdministratorAsync(services).Wait();

            }

            /*app.UseHttpsRedirection();*/

            app.UseCors("AllowReactApp");

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

sign-up.jsx - React Native Expo code:
  const handleContinue = async () => {
    if (currentStage < 4) {
      setCurrentStage(currentStage + 1);
    } else {
      try {
        // Prepare registration data
        const registrationData = {
          fullName: name,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          gender: gender.toUpperCase(),
          weight: parseFloat(weight),
          height: parseFloat(height),
          age: parseInt(age),
          activityLevel: {
            name: activityLevels[activity],
          },
          weeklyWeightChangeGoal: manualKcal ? 0 : weightGoal,
        };

        // Send registration request
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://my ipv4 address:7009/api/user/register",
          registrationData
        );

        if (response.status === 200) {
          router.push("/dashboard");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Registration failed:",
          error.response?.data || error.message
        );
      }
    }
  };


The following may be of of interest: Demystifying How Postman Web works

The following may be of interest: What's my IP.
